# Explicitly or implicitly securing REST functions

Tags: rest

So I am designing a RESTful interface and am working on access control. When a object function is called I test the permissions granted to a user token against the permission requirement of the function.  Since most of the functions are public and read only the requirement list will be full of `function_name=>public`.

Should I require each function to have a permission requirement setting or should I assume that a function is public unless a permission requirement for it is set?

Comment: REST is an architecture, but it sounds like you're talking about a particular tool, language or framework. You should tag your question appropriately to get answers.

Comment: I am more looking for a best practice here rather than a language/tool specific answer.  Should I assume it is a public facing function if there is no requirement or should all public facing function explicitly have the public permission set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it sounds like your RESTful server implementation is a set of functions behind some HTTP gateway, and you're asking if it's OK to use a pattern of "if it's not explicitly restricted, don't restrict it" to each API function's ACL enforcement.

I'd always go with the explicit approach and **force each function to state its ACL restrictions clearly**. If an API function has no permissions set, then nobody should be able to call it. There are a number of reasons behind this:

- If you leave your company and someone else takes over the codebase, they might not understand the implicit behavior, and they might inadvertently make a restricted API public.
- Forcing your API to be explicit about permissions forces you to make clear decisions about each piece of it. Doing it implicitly can lead to things falling through the cracks in that regard.
- If your organization ever has to submit your application's code to be scanned for security, you might get flagged for having implicit behavior such as this. The world of security much prefers the "if it ain't explicitly made public, it ain't" model.